# Merge conflict in a file that wasn't modified in either branch

Tags: git, git-merge, merge-conflict-resolution

When I try to rebase branch `featureX` on `master`, I get a conflict in a file (let's call it `moduleA/foo`) that was not modified in either `master` or `featureX` since they diverged! I checked that with the following log command:

```
git log master...featureX -- moduleA/foo
```

and the result was empty (no commit on either branch touched the file since the branches diverged).

How is this at all possible and what can I do to avoid such misleading conflicts?

Comment: Is it an actual conflict? i.e with '<<<<' markers?

Comment: Yes, it's a "both modified" conflict with conflict markers, and part of the changes inside the markers look like changes I did in `featureX` (but in another file).

Comment: How bizarre. If you don't want the changes, you can probably do `git checkout --theirs -- moduleA/foo` to remove the conflict markers.

Comment: I can (thanks for the commands!), but I would also like to understand why this happened and how can I avoid this :-)

Comment: I can't help you there, I'm afraid.

Comment: The thing is that master doesn't have new version of `moduleA/foo`. This file was not changed at all.

Comment: Try `git log --name-only master..featureX | grep moduleA/foo`, do you get something ?

Comment: @ShmulikKlein no, grep doesn't find anything.

Comment: try `git log featureX..master -- moduleA/foo` see whether you find anything?

Comment: @Xlee nope, it returns nothing.

Comment: If `git diff --name-status master..featureX` returns nothing, they are identical...

Comment: It doesn't report any changes for moduleA/foo file (there are changes in other files). Really strange.

Comment: @ShmulikKlein Agree. One of git log `featureX..master` or `master..featureX` cannot be empty if the file is **not** identical.

Comment: @JanekWarchoł are you sure the contents of *moduleA/foo* in master and featureX are exactly the same?

Comment: @Xlee yes, they are exactly the same (I have compared them manually outside the repo).

Comment: @Oh, i got your point, they're not modified at all after branch diverge. It's possible as `rebase` algorithmic flaws, i suffered similar issues before, i would suggest you to get some temp hooks as adviced in the comments first, and wait for the git professionals to resolve this :D

Answer (score 0):

As @Xlee said, `rebase` can result on changing the hash of the commit and messing up with history.

There are some other possibilities such as :
- `featureX` have been force pushed
- Someone created a commit which changes the `moduleA/foo` file and reverted it on master
- you GIT is playfull and likes to tease you.
Your choice