# Git: Can there be merge conflicts on a file that was never modified in the merge source?

Tags: git, git-merge, merge-conflict-resolution

**TL;DR** : From a purely theoretical perspective, is it possible for Git to report conflicts on a file during the *merging* (not rebasing) of a branch into master if that file has never been modified at all on the branch (which was created directly from master) ?

When I merge my dev branches back into master, I am often presented with conflicts on files that for the life of me I cannot remember to have ever modified - or even opened. So I am trying to understand if - given how Git works, which I don't know well enough - this is actually possible in specific circumstances, or if instead this is impossible so I should focus on something apparently modifying some files in my working tree without me noticing (f.ex. something like Save Actions in Eclipse, automatic formatting, line ending handling etc.).

I am only talking about file conflicts, not tree conflicts nor anything else that might involve file deletions or renamings or movings.

Here is an example of my very simple typical workflow, using EGit with Eclipse (always up to date):

**1**) I create a dev branch from master; I tick the "Configure upstream for push and pull" checkbox, and in the "When pulling" listbox I select "Merge" (the other entries are "Rebase", "Rebase preserving merge commits", "Rebase interactively").

**Nobody else will be committing to that branch, local and remote, *at all*.** Only me and only from one computer.

**2**) I checkout that dev branch and for some days I commit my changes to it everyday. Every single commit is done using "Commit and Push" instead of just "Commit", because I want all my commits to always be on the remote branch too.

On some occasions the Push part of my "Commit and Push" results in a "Rejected - Not fast-forward". In those cases doing a "Pull" and then repeating the Push solves, and some colleagues say that it's normal to have to do a Pull first to avoid that the Push results in "Not fast-forward". This is not the problem though.

**3**) The time comes to merge my dev branch back into master. I pull, switch back to master, pull, select Merge, choose my local dev branch, under "Merge options" I select "Squash", under "Fast forward options" I leave the default "If a fast-forward, only update the branch pointer" (the other options are "If a fast-forward, create a merge commit" and "If not a fast-forward, fail").

Then I click Merge and I get "Result: conflicting", I go to solve those conflicts and in some cases neither the conflicting code shown in red under "Mine" (master) nor the corresponding code shown in red under "Theirs" (my dev branch) is something I wrote. I never modified that file in any part, ever, and yet it has conflicting changes when merging this branch - on which this file has never been changed - into master.

So my question is, from a purely theoretical perspective, do possible situations exist where Git is supposed to report conflicts on a file during the merging of a branch into master although that file has never been modified at all on the branch ? And if yes, does my workflow described above qualify as one of such situations ?

It's not a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41064345/2814308) because that's about using rebase.

Comment: We've had unexplained conflicts as well, and I think we chalked it up to this explanation in our case: Someone did a commit against some other branch. This commit was, due to that other branch being an older version of the product (but still maintained), incompatible with the code on our latest branch. However, we merge from older branches to newer branches to bring bugfixes forward, so a dummy merge was done, from that old branch to our current branch, using "strategy ours" to ignore the changes, then reimplemented. This merge later produced a conflict when merged into other branches.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen Thanks; I'm not skilled enough to tell if such explanation indicates that it _is_ in fact perfectly possible, when merging my branch into master, to have conflicts on files that were never modified on that branch, but it does sound so, and more importantly this makes me realize that there might be things that other team members can do - not to my branch but to master - that will eventually create these unexplained conflicts when I merge my branch into master; I will try to understand if this possibility actually exists because that's something that might actually be happening.

Comment: We specifically did a merge with `-s ours` strategy to say "ignore the changes from that other branch" when merging into the main branch (master in your case). However, when later merging this branch into a feature branch to make it up-to-date in order to fix merge conflicts we **had** introduced, we also got back all the merge conflicts from that other branch that we specifically wanted to ignore. The problem went away eventually when we had no more feature branches created before this strategy-merge but it was a pain while it lasted.

Answer (score 1):

**Update** - realized I forgot to get back to directly answering the question...

---

First things first:  If you are having to pull before you can push, then someone else is making commits on a branch you've modified and are pushing.  Going by your descriptions I can't be 100% sure - I'd need to know specific commands and config settings - but I would bet that means you're mistaken that nobody else is committing to your branch.

I mention this because you're asking if git could theoretically do something because your observations say it may be happening... but those observations are not self-consistent and so cannot be exactly correct.

**Could a merge occur when the branch has no changes?**

Not under the conditions you described.  ... Well, ok, you said "theoretically", so I'll grant that if you're for some reason using an alternate merge tool that's coded to be malicious, I couldn't *prove* this is impossible.  But given my above comments, I'd say I don't believe that's what's going on here.

Say you have

```
R -- x1 ... xN -- A <--(master)
 \
  o1 ... oN -- B <--(branch)
```

and you're about to do a merge of `branch` into `master`.  If there is a conflict on file `foo`, then by definition this means that

(A) there is a change `p1` that was applied to `foo` somewhere between `x1` and `A`,

(B) there is a change `p2` that was applied to `foo` somewhere between `o1` and `B`, and

(C) `p1` and `p2` are deemed to "overlap"

Now there could be lots of ways for `p2` to hide behind that `...` in the diagram.  For example, maybe someone created `branch2` from `branch`, made some changes, and merged `branch2` back into `branch`.  But the merge back to `branch` would *still* be "someone else committing changes to `branch` in that scenario (and the appearance of the merge commit would be an example of when you'd have to pull before you could push).

**So how to tell what's really happening?**

If git reports a conflict, you can get some idea what it's thinking by looking at the conflict markers.  If it's just a matter of changes you didn't remember, perhaps they would look familiar?  But it sounds like that's not the situation.

(The following commands assume the merge is still unfinished; if the merge has been committed then you'd use something like `master^..branch`; the point is the part before the `..` has to refer to the `master` commit prior to the merge.)

So you could see what commits have impacted the file (but aren't in `master`) with something like

```
git log master..branch -- path/to/conflicted/file
```

If that doesn't clear it up, another step would be to try

```
git blame master..branch -- path/to/conflicted/file
```

(You could include `-L` options to zero in on the lines identified on the `branch` side of the conflict markers if you want; see the `git blame` documentation.)

This should tell you who, when, and in what commit.

Comment: Thanks for the great explanation; it will take a while to process it. In the meantime I'd be glad to fix the lack of consistency of my observations but I need to be clear what that is; if it's the claim that despite the conflicts nobody except me commits to the dev branch, I must confirm this, which is the main reason why I'm asking this question, however the next time it happens I will try to take screenshots of the conflict and branch history showing nobody else committed there; if the inconsistencies are elsewhere please point me to them.

Comment: I must also confirm that despite the actual need to pull in order for the push not to result in "Rejected, not fast forward", nobody else ever committed to that branch; quite often I get that "Rejected" when I push, so I pull, then I push again and this time it succeeds, and the remote branch to which I'm pushing has only commits by me (and the local branch too, for that matter), starting from its creation. Here too I will try to document this with screenshots next time it happens.

Comment: My limited understanding of Git is certainly playing a big role here; re _... then someone else is making commits on a branch you've modified and are pushing_, does that include branches other than the currently checked-out branch containing my commits I'm trying to push ? I'm still reasonably sure that all the branches with which I have this issue, local and remote, only receive commits from me, but I never verified if f.ex. while I have branch A checked out and I'm pushing, branch B still from my local repo had unpushed commits (highly unlikely though, as I always click "Commit & Push").

Comment: Whether the push/pull could be due to another branch may depend on config settings or on exact command used. It sounds like you're using an IDE or other UI, so its behavior would also be a factor. So all I can say with the given information is, you're pushing changes to a branch that has received changes that aren't yet in your local repository. But setting aside differing opinions about how to interpret what you've seen, tracking a conflict down with `log` and `blame` commands will show what commit is in question, and then looking at a commit graph should clarify the situation definitively.

Comment: Thanks, the bottom line helps; the only case in which I believe it's possible that I am pushing to a branch that has received changes that aren't yet in my local repository is when said branch is master (in which case it's not only possible but certain). But I'm 100% sure that that Push + Rejected + Pull + Push + OK sequence takes place also for branches where nobody else committed. If there is any info I can provide that might be useful please let me know. The tool used is EGit with Eclipse (always kept up to date). I never issue Git commands directly.